# Need to be able to use javax.speech but I can't figure out how to import it

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have
`import javax.speech.*; import javax.speech.synthesis.*;`
at the top of my java file, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I am using Jetbrains IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition. I am very very new to java and programming in general, and have never dont work with APIs or anything similar to them.

Comment: You need to add the library to your IDE before you can import it into your project. Time for a little [RTFM](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html). Please research before posting questions. You have a world of knowledge available at your fingertips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the Java Speech API, you should learn more about it, e.g. by reading the [Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/speech-api-frequently-asked-questions.html) (FAQ), which starts with:

> *Where can I get the Java Speech API (JSAPI)?*
>
> The Java Speech API (JSAPI) is **not part of the JDK** and Sun does not ship an implementation of JSAPI. Instead, we work with third party speech companies to encourage the availability of multiple implementations.

Later on there is a question you should look into:

> *What JSAPI implementations are now available?*

Comment: Oracle says "The Java Speech API (JSAPI) is not part of the JDK and Sun does not ship an implementation of JSAPI. Instead, we work with third party speech companies to encourage the availability of multiple implementations. " Personally I think that is a cop-out for a company like Oracle or Sun that game before them.